# Formulario de consulta en Django trae datos incorrectos

Tags: python, django

estoy haciendo una consulta para un programa trata sobre formularios y al consultar tengo el problema de que me muestran datos que no debería.

Para ser más específico, tengo estos formularios que están conectados entre sí mediante un ForeignKey :

```
class Cliente(models.Model):

nombre=models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS')

Tipo_doc=models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TIPO_DOCUMENTO, verbose_name='TIPO DE DOCUMENTO', null=True)

identificacion=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='IDENTIFICACIÓN')  

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'CLIENTES'


#----------------------------------------------

class Proceso(models.Model):

    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    Area_Juridica=models.ForeignKey(Areajuridica,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True , verbose_name='ÁREA JURIDICA') 
    Sub_juridica=models.ForeignKey(Subcategoria,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True , verbose_name='TIPO DE PROCESO')
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Proceso {self.pk}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'PROCESOS'


class Entidaddemandada(models.Model):

    proceso = models.ForeignKey(Proceso, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)


    Fechcafinproc=models.DateField(verbose_name='FIN DE LA ETAPA', null=True, blank=True)
```

Y estoy haciendo una búsqueda con un filtro checkbox para que me muestre los procesos que tienen el formulario de entidad-demandada

Este es el campo en el forms : `checkbox_entidad_demandada = forms.BooleanField(required=False)`

Lo que ocurre es que al momento de buscar al haber un cliente que tiene más de 2 procesos , y un proceso tiene el formulario de entidad-demandada y el otro no, éste me arroja los dos lo cual es incorrecto ya que solo me tiene que mostrar los procesos que tengan el formulario de entidad-demandada. Este es mi view :

```
def ConsultarProcesos(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q')

    clientes_con_procesos = Cliente.objects.filter(proceso__isnull=False).distinct().annotate(num_procesos=Count('proceso'))

    consulta_form = BusquedaAvanzadaProcesoForm(request.GET)


    if query:
        clientes_con_procesos = clientes_con_procesos.filter(
            Q(nombre__icontains=query) |
            Q(identificacion__icontains=query) |
            Q(direccion_cli__icontains=query) |
            Q(email__icontains=query) |
            Q(tfno_cli__icontains=query) |
            Q(causante__icontains=query) |
            Q(representante__icontains=query) |
            Q(direccion_rep__icontains=query) |
            Q(tfnorep__icontains=query) |
            Q(departamento__nombre__icontains=query) |
            Q(municipio__nombre__icontains=query) |
            Q(grado__nombre__icontains=query) |
            Q(fuerza__nombre__icontains=query) |
            Q(contacto__icontains=query) |
            Q(asesor_c__nombre__icontains=query) |
            Q(tfnocontacto__icontains=query)
        )

    # Filtrar procesos por formulario de búsqueda avanzada si es válido
    if consulta_form.is_valid():
        Area_Juridica = consulta_form.cleaned_data.get('Area_Juridica')
        Sub_juridica = consulta_form.cleaned_data.get('Sub_juridica')
        entidad = consulta_form.cleaned_data.get('entidad')

        checkbox_entidad_demandada = consulta_form.cleaned_data.get('checkbox_entidad_demandada')

        if Area_Juridica:
            clientes_con_procesos = clientes_con_procesos.filter(proceso__Area_Juridica=Area_Juridica)

        if Sub_juridica:
            clientes_con_procesos = clientes_con_procesos.filter(proceso__Sub_juridica=Sub_juridica)

        if entidad:
            clientes_con_procesos = clientes_con_procesos.filter(proceso__entidaddemandada__entidad__icontains=entidad)

        if  checkbox_entidad_demandada:
            clientes_con_procesos = clientes_con_procesos.filter(proceso__entidaddemandada__isnull=False)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(clientes_con_procesos, 40)

    try:
        clientes_con_procesos = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        clientes_con_procesos = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        clientes_con_procesos = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    procesos = Proceso.objects.filter(cliente__in=clientes_con_procesos)
    context = {
        'paginator': paginator,
        'clientes_con_procesos': clientes_con_procesos,
        'query': query,
        'consulta_form': consulta_form,
        'procesos': procesos,
    }
    return render(request, 'arcapp/consultarprocesos.html', context)
```

Se agradece cualquier respuesta que me ayude